# RHEL 7 collectd dbi freetds issues

Tags: dbi, freetds, collectd, rhel7

I can't seem to get the dbi plugin working for collectd on RHEL 7. I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server using the FreeTDS driver, but collectd/dbi can't find it.

**I've installed the latest collectd:**
Name        : collectd
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.5.2
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 1.8 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : Statistics collection daemon for filling RRD files
License     : GPLv2

**I've installed collectd-dbi:**
Name        : collectd-dbi
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.5.2
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 32 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : /collectd-dbi-5.5.2-1.el7.x86_64
Summary     : DBI plugin for collectd
License     : GPLv2

**I've installed FreeTDS:**
Name        : freetds
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 0.95.81
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 2.7 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : epel
Summary     : Implementation of the TDS (Tabular DataStream) protocol
License     : LGPLv2+ and GPLv2+

**collectd shows an error when trying to load FreeTDS:**
dbi plugin: cdbi_connect_database: dbi_driver_open_r (FreeTDS) failed.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fighting the same problem myself, and while I haven't yet got it working I'm pretty sure you need DBD::Sybase in addition to collectd, collectd-dbi and freetds. I grabbed it from http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/ME/MEWP/DBD-Sybase-1.15.tar.gz.

With luck you'll get past where I'm at, which is that Perl says the driver is available, but the collectd plugin can't reference it.

Seeming success on the perl side:

```
cat ./test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

#Prints a list of the available DBD drivers.
@available_drivers = DBI->available_drivers;
print ("The available DBD drivers are: @available_drivers.\n");

$ ./test.pl
The available DBD drivers are: DBM ExampleP File Gofer Oracle Proxy Sponge Sybase mysql.
```

But I get this error in the collectd log:

```
[2016-09-27 14:18:09] dbi plugin: cdbi_connect_database: dbi_driver_open_r (Sybase) failed.
[2016-09-27 14:18:09] dbi plugin: Maybe the driver isn't installed? Known drivers are:
[2016-09-27 14:18:09] dbi plugin: * mysql
```

That mysql driver became available after I installed the libdbi-dbd-mysql rpm, but no love yet getting it to recognize the Sybase driver.

Comment: I did try to install DBD-Sybase, but still the same issues. Getting this going on Ubuntu is very simple and all you need to do is install libdbd-freetds and the DBI plugin works. Not sure why there isn't a similar package for RHEL.